# What is the equivalent of xalan:component and xalan:script in saxon?

Tags: xslt, saxon, xalan

How do I port this to Saxon 9.5?

```
<xalan:component prefix="my-ext" elements="timelapse" functions="getdate">
    <xalan:script lang="javascript">
       javascript code
    </xalan:script>
</xalan:component>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saxon allows you to write extension functions in Java, but not in Javascript. So the best way to convert this depends on what the function is doing. In very many cases, things that needed extension functions in XSLT 1.0 can be done directly in XSLT 2.0/XPath 2.0, either by calling the much more extensive set of built-in functions, or by writing your own using xsl:function. In other cases, you may have to rewrite the function in Java.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a direct equivalent. XSLT 2.0 has `xsl:function` to write functions directly with XSLT instead of writing extension functions in another language like Javascript. And it has support for date and dateTime, duration and other data types. So that is what you can do in XSLT 2.0, write functions in XSLT and make use of the rich XSLT/XPath data type system.

Comment: For the record: http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/extensibility/instructions.html